# Rails / Ruby not following Rublar on regular expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following expression that I have tested in Rubular and that successfully matches against a snippet of HTML:

```
Official Website<\/h3>\s*<p><a href="([^"]*)"
```

However, when I run the expression in Ruby, using the following code, it returns no matches. I've reduced it down to "Official\s*Website" and it matches that, but nothing further.

Are there any additional options I need to set, or anything else that I need to do to configure Ruby/Rails to start tracking Rubular?

```
  matches = sidebar.match(/Official\s*Website<\/h3>\s*<p><a href="([^"]*)"/)
  if matches.nil?
    puts "no matches"
  else
    puts "matches"
  end
```

This is the relevant part of the snippet I'm matching against:

```
 <h3>Official Website</h3><p><a href="http://website.com" target="_blank">website.com</a></p>
```

Comment: what is the snippet that you are matching against?

Comment: Instead of using a regular expression to parse HTML, you could always use [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/). HTML is such a loose "standard" that it is very hard to parse correctly. The insertion of another attribute in the `<a>` tag, or some errant spaces will wreck your regexp.

Comment: @phoet - I added the snippet to the question

Comment: @tadman - I actually use nokogiri elsewhere, but this is a harder one to parse using a css/xpath path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your regular expression is correct. rubular should be working the same way your code does.

i tested it against ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3

```
irb(main):006:0>  sidebar = ' <h3>Official Website</h3><p><a href="http://website.com" target="_blank">website.com</a></p>'
=> " <h3>Official Website</h3><p><a href=\"http://website.com\" target=\"_blank\">website.com</a></p>"
irb(main):007:0> sidebar.match(/Official\s*Website<\/h3>\s*<p><a href="([^"]*)"/)
=> #<MatchData "Official Website</h3><p><a href=\"http://website.com\"" 1:"http://website.com">
```

-

```
1.9.3p0 :005 > sidebar = ' <h3>Official Website</h3><p><a href="http://website.com" target="_blank">website.com</a></p>'
 => " <h3>Official Website</h3><p><a href=\"http://website.com\" target=\"_blank\">website.com</a></p>" 
1.9.3p0 :006 > sidebar.match(/Official\s*Website<\/h3>\s*<p><a href="([^"]*)"/)
 => #<MatchData "Official Website</h3><p><a href=\"http://website.com\"" 1:"http://website.com">
```

if you want to quickly check why stuff is not working, you should try it in IRB or in your rails console. most of the times it's typo or bad encoding.